# How to install jq on amazon EC2 instance

Tags: linux, jq, amazon-linux

I am trying to install jq JSON parser on amazon instance, unfortunately, i'm not able to install it can someone guide me.

Answer (score 61, accepted):

jq is available in the yum repo so run the following

```
sudo yum install jq
```

will install jq on the instance

Comment: Sadly currently (Feb 2022) this will install 1.5 (released in 2015) rather than 1.6 (released in 2018) despite that being 4 years old already.

Comment: Even if you install it you get this: -bash: /usr/local/bin/jq: cannot execute binary file

Answer (score 13):

Tried yum install jq on RHEL but did not work as this package is not there..However following commands made the JQ available on my RHEL machine on AWS...

```
wget -O jq https://github.com/stedolan/jq/releases/download/jq-1.6/jq-linux64
chmod +x ./jq
cp jq /usr/bin
```